# Syntax for a referenceable concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to mimic the `can-referece` exposition only concept, that can be found in the new C++20 iterator concepts.

Extracted from `cppreferece`:

```
template <class I>

concept input_or_output_iterator =
  requires(I i) {
    { *i } -> /*can-reference*/;
  } &&
  std::weakly_incrementable<I>;
```

So, I tried to implement the concepts, as follows:

```
    /**
     * @brief ALias for define that a template parameter T is referenceable = T&
     */
    template<typename T>
    using template_arg_with_ref = T&;

    /**
     * @brief satisfied if and only if the type is referenceable (in particular, not void)
     */
    template<typename T>
    concept can_reference = requires() { typename template_arg_with_ref<T>; };

    /**
     * @brief satisfied if and only if the type is dereferenceable (in particular, not void)
     */
    template<typename T>
    concept dereferenceable = requires(T& t) {
        { *t } -> can_reference;
    };
```

which compiles perfectly fine using `Clang 15.0.0`.

However, if I try to remove verbosity, an define directly that a type `T` is *referenceable*, without the alias:

```
    /**
     * @brief satisfied if and only if the type is referenceable (in particular, not void)
     */
    template<typename T>
    concept can_reference = requires() { typename T&; };

    /**
     * @brief satisfied if and only if the type is dereferenceable (in particular, not void)
     */
    template<typename T>
    concept dereferenceable = requires(T& t) {
        { *t } -> can_reference;
    };
```

the compiler complains, and throws the following error:

```
error: expected ';' at end of requirement
    concept can_reference = requires() { typename T&; };
                                                   ^
                                                   ;
```

- Is not possible to use directly `T&` as shown above?
- Or I am just making a syntax error, and don't know the correct way of write the concept without the alias type?

Comment: We note that the ["exposition only" code](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.synopsis) does it in two steps, using a `with-reference<T>` helper. Probably not by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar for a type requirement is given in [[expr.prim.req.type]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.req.type#nt:type-requirement) and allows only for a (nested) [*type-name*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.type.simple#nt:type-name), not a more general [*type-id*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.name#nt:type-id) (which is used e.g. in template arguments).

A *type-name* (possibly prefixed with a [*nested-name-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:nested-name-specifier)) can only be the name of a type (including required template argument lists), but no other type specifiers can be included. Adding a reference qualifier, `const`/`volatile` qualifier or forming other compound types such as arrays, function types, etc. in the requirement is not allowed. This is in line with how `typename` can be used in other contexts. It always can only have a nested *type-name* follow it.

So you always need to defer an alias or you can use the template argument of e.g. `std::type_identity_t`:

```
typename std::type_identity_t<T&>;
```